# Memory leak when using tf.data Datasets with shuffle

Tags: tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory, tensorflow-datasets

I have a memory leak somehow when I create my tf.data.dataset pipeline, but I don't know where.
My code works fine with ImageDataGenerator but is really slow.
Reading a lot of documentation I thought it might be albumentations.

However I now switched my transform to be entirely in tensorflow:

```
def map_data(inputs, outputs):
image = inputs['image_input']
image = parse_image(image)
image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32) / 255.0
image = tf.image.resize(image, size = [224, 224])
image = tf.image.random_flip_left_right(image)
image = tf.image.random_flip_up_down(image)
image = tf.image.random_brightness(image, max_delta = 0.5)
#image = tf.expand_dims(image, axis=3)
other = parse_image(inputs['other_input'])
other = tf.cast(other, tf.float32) / 255.0
other = tf.image.resize(other, size = [224, 224])
other = tf.image.random_flip_left_right(other)
other = tf.image.random_flip_up_down(other)
other = tf.image.random_brightness(other, max_delta = 0.5)


return {'image_input': image, 'other_input': other}, outputs
```

And I made the shuffle buffer extremely small:

```
        #dataset = dataset.prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
    AUTOTUNE = tf.data.AUTOTUNE
    dataset = (dataset
        .shuffle(32)
        .map(map_data, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
        .cache()
        .batch(32)
        .prefetch(AUTOTUNE)
    )
```

Could autotune cause this?
On Colab I usually hit the RAM restart at 500 batches

I would like to use tf.data.datasets because it's really much faster if possible.

Thank you for anyone who can point me to the flaw in my code, I have always used generators and only recently made the switch.

Comment: Can you remove `.cache()` and see what happens?

Comment: I had tried that too, same thing. Now I moved cache to before map as I read somewhere this may help. Epoch will end in like 10 minutes, let you know, thanks !!!

Comment: You need to first provide evidence of the memory leak

Comment: @M.Innat seems like moving .cache() after the mapping functions did work. I followed it here https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/guide/data_performance.ipynb#scrollTo=hfueG0Wj-jMR as the transforms seem to use most memory. Now I'm into the second epoch
Hopefully it'll hold

Comment: @M.Innat Hmm so that's really weird, I'm guessing your first thought was correct, though this was also the first thing I tried. It must have been caching op. Because I'm now a few epochs in and nothing has crashed. So removing it the first time should have also fixed it.
I'm suspecting I may not have reinitialized the dataset correctly then. Cheers